# Home Directory Can't Fetch Permission

Tags: permissions

I can't seem to fetch my users given permission to my home directory (which in this case, would be me...but the loading spinner just keeps on spinning. Any request for permission to create or write hidden files (like .zshrc) is denied...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NEJy.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this situation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: home directory of what? a web server or anything else? please improve your question with proper information to get an answer

Comment: Ah sorry for the vagueness...I was so tired yesterday of trying to solve this problem. The image is the home directory of my macbook. I am logged in as the sole admin of my mac but I'm denied access to my home directory and the hidden files in it...

Answer (score 2):

Just talked to applecare. If anyone needs to reset their permission settings, copy this into the terminal and should work!

diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if your questions don't meet the StackOverflow guideline your questions section will be disabled, be aware of it.